# How do I install on Windows a printer shared from cups on Linux?

Tags: windows, drivers, printing, cups, postscript

I got an industrial printer that doesn't have drivers for Windows. Someone wrote a driver for Linux and it works great.

I want to print from Windows.

The Adobe PS Drivers are discontinued and all links are wiped from the web. They won't work on x64 anyway because the installer is 16 bit.

The Cups PS drivers that were available on their website are gone and replaced with a lame "Free binaries are available elsewhere - search Google to find them." message. Thanks, it's great security practice to install unsigned drivers from random websites.

I found some 10 years old drivers from an unnamed bitbucket repository: https://bitbucket.org/oherrala/puppet/src/933249d58d25/cups/files/drivers/x64/, I tried them in a VM, replacing the PPD with mine, but Windows doesn't accept them and refuses to install

I must use the PPD because if I use something like the "MS Publisher Color printer" generic driver, it doesn't have the right paper sizes, this printer doesn't even support letter/a4 size

I tried [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1590186/10686) where you replace the generic Microsoft PS PPD with your custom one but  looks like doesn't work anymore on latest Windows 10, it says the driver is corrupted

I tried to create a generic postscript inf file from [this Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/installing-a-pscript-minidriver) but Windows doesn't recognize it as a valid driver inf file

There's a way to install a printer on Windows just from the PPD?

Comment: It is not off topic. I am asking how to install a postscript printer in Windows. I don't ask recommendation about products, service or learning materials.

Comment: For not being a request for software recommendation you spend 3 paragraphs going on about how you'd use a particular set of software, and then say you cannot find that software where you expect to find it. I agree it's not software recommendation request, but you could edit the question to make it look less like one.